# Azure architecture best suited to save JSON from API to a Data Lake Store?

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake, azure-iot-hub, azure-eventhub

I am looking forward to build an endpoint capable of receiving JSON objects and saving them into ADLS. So far I have tried several different combinations using Functions, Event Hubs, and Stream Analytics. The problem is: no solution so far seems ideal.

**TL;DR** In my scenario, I have a few set of users that will send me JSON data through an API, and I need to save it inside ADLS, separated by user. What is the best way of doing so?

Could anyone shed me some light? Thanks in advance.

**WARNING: LONG TEXT AHEAD**

Let me explain my findings so far:

**Functions**

Advantages

1. single solution approach - solving the scenario with a single service
2. built-in authorization
3. organization - saving user's files to separate folders inside ADLS
4. HTTP endpoint - to send data only a POST is required
5. cheap & pay-as-you-go - charged per request

Disadvantages

1. bindings & dependencies - Functions doesn't have ADLS bindings. To authorize and use ADLS, I need to install extra dependencies and manually manage its credentials. I was only able to do it with C#, but haven't tested with other languages. May also be a drawback, although I can't confirm.
2. File management - saving 1 file per request is not suggested by ADLS. The alternative would be to append to files and manage its size. This means more code compared to the other solutions.

**Event Hub**

Advantages

1. no code at all - all I need is enabling data capture

Disadvantages

1. one event hub per user - the only way of separating data inside ADLS through event hub's capture capability requires using one event hub per user
2. price - capturing one-event-hub-per-user increases the prices drastically
3. authorization - sending events are not as trivial as doing a POST

**Functions + Event Hub**

Using Event Hub with Functions mitigate Functions disadvantages, but have the same drawbacks (except auth) of Event Hub

**Functions + Event Hub + Stream Analytics**

Although I would be able to have a single event hub without capture, using Stream Analytics SQL as a filter to direct each user's data to its specific folder, it would be a limiting factor. I have tried it and it gets slower as the SQL gets bigger.

**IoT Hub**

IoT Hub has routing, but it is not as dynamic as I require.

Could anyone shed me some light? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks for documenting the pros/cons of each method. Have you considered building a .Net web API? This would be the most custom of solutions.

Comment: Why the requirement to store it in ADLS? If it is only for querying purposes then blob storage will do as you can query it directly using u-sql. In that case I'd say go for an azure function

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Definitely. I thought about using Functions since it is extremely scalable and cheap. I am very biased toward using a custom built .net API. Nowadays this is the way I receive data, although it goes straight to a SQL Server. Thanks for the response!

Comment: @PeterBons I thought ADLS was better suited than Blob Storage if using with ADLA? I can not confirm that, but it made sense to me. Maybe I am wrong.

Comment: Not in my experience, running u-sql jobs over blob storage data works fine here. It is natively supported, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-analytics/u-sql/input-files-u-sql

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite see the disadvantages of using only Azure Functions to write data to ADLS.

- As long as you don't write lots of small files, writing 1 file per request should not really be an issue
- Use the [.NET SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-store/data-lake-store-data-operations-net-sdk) should be pretty straightforward even without an existing binding
- To solve the authentication piece: Use Managed Service Identity (MSI) and KeyVault to store your client secrets there. MSI support in the SDK is apparently on the [roadmap](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-service-identity/tutorial-windows-vm-access-datalake#get-an-access-token-using-the-vm-msi-and-use-it-to-call-the-azure-data-lake-store-filesystem) and would then make this very easy indeed.
- You save yourself the extra cost of an Event Hub and I don't see a real value add through it

Comment: Thanks for the response. The intention is indeed writing one file per request, but I will most likely work with millions of files per day. I would definitely need to work with file appending. I will take a deep look on MSI. Thanks!